# Generate self-referencing generic type with JavaPoet

Tags: java, generics, self-reference, javapoet

How could I generate the following:

```
class A extends B<A> {}
```

I'm stuck at constructing the ParameterizedTypeName to add the super class, I cannot seem to find a way to reference the type of A before it is constructed...

Any pointers? Is this at all possible?

Comment: It was not me, but maybe because you didn't show anything you've tried? Just a thought.

Comment: I thought about that as well, but there is not really something to show... I indicated that I'm trying to construct an instance of ParameterizedType but that I couldn't figure out how to specify the arguments...

Anyway, it's solved!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Classname.get("com.example.project", "A")` to get the `A` and `ParameterizedTypeName` for the `B<A>`.

Comment: That worked indeed, I found an issue describing this as well: https://github.com/square/javapoet/issues/294